# What is the term for functions that looks differently depending on their interval?

Tags: functions, terminology

Say i have a function $f(x)$ that looks like this
$f(x) = -x^2$ (for $x<5$)
$f(x) = 3x$ (for $x≥5$)
What is this type of function (that has an entierly different appearence depending on its interval) called?

Comment: Piecewise defined function, I would believe.

Comment: Piecewise defined function is the most general name. In some context it is also called piecewise polynomial function or piecewise smooth function.